# Mixing Request Forms and Files: pass additional parameters in a post request when file is transmitted

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

In the FAST API documentation, the below example is listed as a reference how to pass additional parameters in a post request when file is transmitted.

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/files/")
async def create_file(
    file: bytes = File(...), token: str = Form(...)
):
```

When I make a post request as below I get:

```
requests.post(URL, files={'file': hdf5_file, 'token': 'teststring'})

422 Unprocessable Entity
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'model_str'],
   'msg': 'str type expected',
   'type': 'type_error.str'}]}
```

Why is token not recognized as a string? It's not clear from the documentation how a post request that mixes forms with files would need to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `requests` [use](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) the parameter `files` to upload files, and `data` for sending extra form data. In this case, everything will be sent as different parts with content-type `multipart/form-data`:

```
requests.post(URL, files={'file': hdf5_file}, data={'token': 'teststring'})
```